# Obtain more detailled information about available update package

Tags: 14.04, updates, packaging

Could anyone tells me how to obtain more information about available update packages on Ubuntu (**build time, registration date** etc..) more than what **apt-cache show** command displays. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

install apt-listchanges this will show all changes between current installed package and getting updated package before updating the system.

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-listchanges
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal but is there a way to get those informations using native tools on Ubuntu?